# Remove filesystem from an unpartitioned disk

Tags: centos, filesystems, fdisk, parted

I have an un-partitioned 500GB disk with a ext3 fs using the entire disk.

If I make sure there are no partitions on the disk using fdisk or parted, "ssm list" will still show an ext3 fs on the disk (because this file system exists outside of any partitions"

I am also still able to mount the fs and use it.

How can I remove any reference to this filesystem?

I'm using centos7  and there is no data on the disk that I want to keep.
The server is running in a VM, I could just add a new disk to it, but I want to know how to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One easy (and heavy handed) way to do this would be to wipe the whole contents of the disk.  The simplest way to do that would be to use `dd`:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/<disk> bs=1M count=500000
```

By the time the command ends (maybe an hour?) your whole disk will be filled with zeros.

If you're in a rush, you could kill the process with <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> after a few seconds/minutes to see if you've wiped enough data for the disk to be considered as blank.

Comment: This is what I went with in the end, sledgehammer! I wondered if there was a "proper" way to do it

Comment: I suppose you would have to dissect `ssm` to figure out how it checks for valid file-systems.  Maybe it looks for the 1st superblock? Once you find that, you'd have to either remove it manually, or write a small utility to do this for you.  Alternatively... the sledgehammer always works :-)

Answer (score 11):

An alternative to scrubbing all the data is to use the `wipefs` utility from the `util-linux` package.  Run it without arguments to list the signatures found on the device:

```
# wipefs /dev/sdb
offset               type
----------------------------------------------------------------
0x0                  xfs   [filesystem]
                     UUID:  72f2a607-8af7-44c0-83c2-f1565cd68a1a
```

Then run it with `-a` to erase those signatures:

```
# wipefs -a /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb: 4 bytes were erased at offset 0x00000000 (xfs): 58 46 53 42

# wipefs /dev/sdb
#
```

This will **not** delete your data.  It'll just remove the filesystem headers so that it's not mountable.